# Java downcast on Custom Class extending Date - runtime error

Tags: java, android, casting

I have a class like this:

```
public class DateS extends Date {
    public DateS yesterday(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(this);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        return (DateS) cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

It can be successfully built. At runtime, when I call `date.yesterday()`, a `Cannot cast 'java.util.Date' to 'myproject.package.DateS'` are throwed.

I need to know why and what can I do to fix this.

Comment: Well, `Calendar.getTime()` doesn't return an instance of `myproject.package.DateS`, so you can't do that cast. To fix it, you can just return a `Date`, rather than a `DateS`.

Comment: On Swift when you create a extension of a class you can add functionalities to them. What is equivalent in Java?
How can I add new attributes and methods to Date class directly?

Comment: @JorgeHenrique there is no equivalent to that in java. You will probably need to wrap the returned `Date` in your `DateS` class. then you can delegate and also add additional functionality.

Comment: By the way, in java.time, get *yesterday* more simply:  `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).minusDays( 1 )`

Answer (score 3):

Because `Calendar` does not make a `DateS` it uses a different implementation of `Date`.

In order to cast to a `DateS` the object has to be an instance of `DateS` or a child of that class. Since `Calendar` doesn't return an instance of `DateS` you can't cast it. It compiles just fine because theoretically it could work if the returned date was of the correct type, and the compiler can't tell.